# how to run condition in php array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

hi i have array as given below i need to run logical condition.
please suggest me how to run this code then output will match array conditions.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [match] => FALSE
        [coundition] => 
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [coundition] => or            
        [match] => TRUE

    )

    [2] => Array
    (
    [coundition] => and            
    [match] => FALSE

    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [coundition] => and            
        [match] => TURE
    )

)
```

want to run coundition like

```
if($match[0]==TRUE || $match[1]==TRUE && $match[2]==TRUE && $match[3]==FALSE  )
{
    $output=1;
}else
{
    $output=0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `$myArray[0]['match']` instead of `$match[0]` to get the value of the `match` keys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, then this would help you!

```
<?php

$arr = array(array("MATCH" => "FALSE", "CONDITION" => "OR"),
             array("MATCH" => "TRUE", "CONDITION" => "AND"),
             array("MATCH" => "TRUE", "CONDITION" => "AND"),
             array("MATCH" => "FALSE", "CONDITION" => "OR")

);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";


if($arr[0]["MATCH"]=="TRUE" || $arr[1]["MATCH"]=="TRUE" && $arr[2]["MATCH"]=="TRUE"
        && $arr[3]["MATCH"]=="FALSE" ) {
    echo "The output is 1";
}

else {
    echo "The output is 0";
}

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MATCH] => FALSE
        [CONDITION] => OR
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [MATCH] => TRUE
        [CONDITION] => AND
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [MATCH] => TRUE
        [CONDITION] => AND
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [MATCH] => FALSE
        [CONDITION] => OR
    )

)

The output is 1
```

[image]

Comment: how to run condition in side array with match .